# Voltage offset on comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, comparator

I want to make an ideal diode using a comparator and one p-channel mosfet. I'm looking for a cheapest method to add a few millivolts (25mV - 50mV) as an offset to one of op-amp's inputs just to ensure that the mosfet would be forward biased.

Comment: a couple of resistors?

Comment: You have many choices on input bias current voltage drop, balancing Req input offset V, input offset current, thermal drift etc so make wise choices in each R selection and Comparator to meet your target offset.  Which spec do you not understand?

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't be there any problem due to tolerance? I believe that isn't precise method. I'd like something that can be in pass production

Comment: Try looking up a precision rectifier or, are you after a power diode with zero volt drop?

Comment: I'd like to saturate a p-channel mosfet when its Vsd voltage is positive. Ideal diode make this but using a discrete mosfet and an op amp you could make it cheaper. I want to use it in battery backup system. My two voltages are close similar. But I do worry about resistor's tolerance. I will update a schematic as soon as possible.